# How can I get the URL of the aspx page from code behind?

Tags: asp.net, url

How can I get the url of the active aspx page from the code behind so that I can assign it to a string variable?

Does it make a difference in what page-lifecycle stage I call this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you're on a page:

```
Request.Url.ToString();
```

if you are a class library elsewhere

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString();
```

Doesn't matter about lifecycle

Answer (score 1):

To Get the path

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Path
```

Or you can also do..

```
 Request.Url.AbsoluteUri
```

And it does not matter in page life cycle.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something other than Request.Url?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get

page.aspx
from

```
http://localhost:2806/Pages/page.aspx
```

try this:

```
    Dim url_array() As String = Request.Url.AbsolutePath.Split("/")
    Response.Write(url_array(url_array.Length - 1))
```